# Why does Kotlin need to design 'also' keyword?

Tags: android, kotlin

I think that *Code A* is equivalent to *Code B*, I can't understand why Kotlin need to design 'also' keyword. It make programmer  puzzle.

**Code A**

```
val list = mutableListOf<Int>().also { 
   it.add(1) 
}
```

**Code B**

```
val list = mutableListOf<Int>().apply { 
   add(1) 
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@fatihcoskun/kotlin-scoping-functions-apply-vs-with-let-also-run-816e4efb75f5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`also` is not a keyword, it's just a function. It can be preferred to `apply` when e.g.:

1. You want to use the current `this` instead of `apply`'s receiver parameter:

   ```
   val list = mutableListOf<MyClass>().also { 
       add(this) // won't work with apply
   }
   ```
2. You want to give a name to the parameter:

   ```
   mutableListOf<MyClass>().also { list -> ... }
   ```